# Create Excel file with ExcelLibrary

Tags: c#, excellibrary

I use ExcelLibrary to create an excel from a `DataSet`. I use the below code to create a `DataSet` and create Excel.

```
DataTable dtTable = new DataTable();
dtTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("name", typeof(string)));
DataRow dr = dtTable.NewRow();
dr[0] = "test";
dtTable.Rows.Add(dr);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(dtTable);

ExcelLibrary.DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook(textBox1.Text, ds);
```

But when the excel is created, there are no rows in Excel.

Comment: Questions are more easily answered if you include the code..

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

> `DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
>       dt.Columns.Add("Name"); 
>       dt.Columns.Add("Code");`
>
> `DataRow row1 = dt.NewRow(); 
>       row1["Name"] = "Abundantcode"; 
>       row1["Code"] = "1-1-1"; 
>       dt.Rows.Add(row1);`

[Source](http://abundantcode.com/how-to-create-datatable-and-add-rows-in-c/).

Hope it helps!

Comment: doesn't work, the dataTable that i created is correct,but when create excel doesn't show data

Answer (score 0):

Give a name to your datatable. That will create the sheet name
dtTable.TableName = "Sheet1"